# AutoGenerateEditButton is ignored in C# code for DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Edit - Thanks for your replies so far and sorry for not stating exactly what the problem was. The actual markup code is

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvwSomeDetailsView" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SomeDataSourceID">
  <Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SomeText" SortExpression="SomeText">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <cc1:Editor ID="txtDescription" runat="server" 
          Content='<%# Bind("SomeText") %>' />
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Bind"SomeText") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/img/cancel.png" 
      EditImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" InsertImageUrl="~/img/insert.png"
      UpdateImageUrl="~/img/save.png" ShowEditButton="True" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I'm not too sure whether setting the ShowEditButton property should be removed, but when I tried to do that I still couldn't set it programmatically.

Now in the code behind file I reduced the Page_Load method to this

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  dvwSomeDetailsView.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that by changing the assignment in the Page_Load method I can hide / show the Edit button, but that does not work. When playing around in the markup file I can make the button show up or hide, but I can never change it from the code behind file.

I also tried to explicitly call dvwSomeDetailsView.DataBind after setting the property, but this also didn't work. Overriding OnPreRender and placing the code from the Page_Load method in their didn't do anything to improve this either.

Maybe I'm thinking too complicated - shouldn't there be an easy way to set programmatically whether the button should / shouldn't show?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Gorgsenegger

Comment: false is the default for the property. Those lines of code and markup shouldn't do anything. Do you modify the property anywhere else in your code? What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to do anything in terms of setting the aforementioned property"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code redacted behind the

```
[... Some Stuff...]
```

contains a call to detailsView.DataBind() (either directly or through Page.DataBind()), then that is your problem.  The AutoGenerateEditButton property must be set prior to calling DataBind on the DetailsView.